# How to log a project that is being deployed from Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, installation

I have a C# project written using Visual Studio Express  2013 for Windows Desktop. When I run the project in debug mode via Visual Studio (on Windows 8 Pro) it executes just fine, and so does copying the files out of the bin directory.

I need to deploy to a Windows 7 Embedded System with the correct version of .NET Framework. I tried:

1. copying the files over with the .dll and everythig from the bin folder and when starting I get no error, but doesn't start at all. I get no information at all.
2. tried the one click installer (choosing the option to install from dvd) and it seemed to install fine, but when I start it, I get same issue. Not starting, and no messages.
3. I also tried the Advanced Installer (free version) and when importing the visual studio project files it fails with the message "Failed to start Visual Studio. Error: Invalid Class String"

**[UPDATE]** Advanced Installer cannot import VS Express solutions because the API from VS that provides assistance on import is not available for VS Express edition. Only solutions created with paid editions of VS can be imported in Advanced Installer.

So how can I log or see what is happening to debug this?

Comment: It seems like the .NET Framework version you used to build your application, does not match with those on Windows 7 machine. You can set target framework version in your project's settings or update .NET Framework at target machine to latest version, it has backward compatibility with previous ones.

Comment: Just a wild guess... Have you tried installing/running your project with an Admin-account?

Comment: @Thorias: Yes, I did try running it as an admin account as well.

Comment: @kravasb: I verified in the registry that .NET Framework 4.5.2 is installed. My project targets 4.5.

Comment: Does that problem occur only on target machine? I mean, have you tried to run your app on other machines than target one? You can also use [windows logs](http://www.windows-commandline.com/windows-event-viewer-run-command/) to get more info

Comment: @Bogdan Mitrache: Can you upgrade a VS Express solution to a regular VS so it will work with Advanced Installer?

Comment: I don't think you need to upgrade the solution, from what I read is not even possible. The solution you need is to have VS Professional installed on the machine, so that Advanced Installer can use it to import the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907420/is-there-a-need-to-convert-a-visual-studio-express-solution-to-a-visual-studio-p

Comment: @kravasb: I have now tried to run it on both the target and development machine with same problem. I also used the Advanced Installer successfully after installing VS 2013 Pro, but hits the same problem.

Comment: Kind of at a loss here, as you need to be able to see an error in order to debug it. Does Windows keep any logs of crashing programs?